# Google Map API shows incorrect travel speed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-1

I have developed a map that allow user to track the mobile devices. But I have achieved wrong speed travelled of the device on the road. For example, the device only travel 7.1kmph in the Google Map Api, but the actual speed travelled on the road was 30kmph.

And mind to tell me what is the default unit speed used in Google Map API?

Can someone tell me what is the issue of this scenario?

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits), the accuracy of speed limit data returned by the Google Maps Roads API cannot be guaranteed. The speed limit data provided is not real-time, and may be estimated, inaccurate, incomplete, and/or outdated.

Comment: Thanks KENdi, I have tried again when I'm travelling 80kmh on the road, Im am still getting 120kmh on my web base application. This is far from how fast I have travelled. Currently still looking for solution to solve this issue.